# How to debug a program with a parameter

Tags: gdb, executable

I'm trying to debug a program using only one parameter that seems to be a password. My goal is to get the correct parameter (the password). (It's a challenge from a friend, nothing illegal here).

The only times I debugged programs, the use of "run" was possible. Here, it seems I can't do anything with this program without executing it.

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You want to achieve what exactly? "Extract password" is not a command common debugging tools support.

Comment: I want to get the parameter (password). It's an executable that needs a password in order to run.

Comment: `gdb --args program param`?

Comment: it works, but i'm not really sure how I can get the plain text password out of this command

Comment: How should *we* know? What kind of help are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve what I want to do ?

Yes: you need to disassemble the program, understand its control flow, examine the data it uses, and effectively reconstruct it back to `C` (or any other high-level language).

Once you've done this, the answer will be obvious.

This is called reverse engineering, and there are many articles explaining the process. Use your favorite search engine to find them.